# sum numpy ndarray with 3d array along a given axis 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy ndarray with shape (2,3,3),for example:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6],
    [12, 34, 90]],

   [[ 4,  5,  6],
    [ 2,  5,  6],
    [ 7,  3,  4]]])
```

I am getting lost in np.sum(above ndarray ,axis=1), why that answer is:

```
array([[17, 41, 99],
   [13, 13, 16]])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A
> 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running
> vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running
> horizontally across columns (axis 1).

Let A be the array, then in your example when the axis is 1, [i,:,k] is added. Likewise, for axis 0, [:,j,k] are added and when axis is 2, [i,j,:] are added.

```
A = np.array([
   [[ 1,  2,  3],[ 4,  5,  6], [12, 34, 90]],
   [[ 4,  5,  6],[ 2,  5,  6], [ 7,  3,  4]]
])

np.sum(A,axis = 0)
    array([[ 5,  7,  9],
           [ 6, 10, 12],
           [19, 37, 94]])
np.sum(A,axis = 1)
    array([[17, 41, 99],
           [13, 13, 16]])
np.sum(A,axis = 2)
    array([[ 6, 15,136],
           [15, 13, 14]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the inout array `A` and the output array `B = np.sum(A, axis=1)`.
It has elements `B[i, j]` which are calculated as

```
B[i, j] = np.sum(A[i, :, j])
```

E.g. the first element `B[0,0] = 17` is the sum of the elements in

```
A[0, :, 0] = array([ 1,  4, 12])
```

Answer (score 0):

np.sum() is adding the values vertically, the first element of each sub-list in the first list is added: 1+4+12 = 17, then the second 2+5+34=41 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The array has shape `(2,3,3)`; axis 1 is the middle one, of size 3.  Eliminate that by `sum` and you are left with `(2,3)`, the shape of your result.

Interpreting 3d is a little tricky.  I tend to think of this array as having 2 planes, each plane has 3 rows, and 3 columns.  The sum on axis 1 is over the rows of each plane.

```
1 + 4 + 12 == 17
```

In effect you are reducing each 2d plane to a 1d row.