# Predicted mask image has wrong dimension unet- TypeError: Invalid shape (2023, 2023, 256) for image data

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-segmentation, kaggle, semantic-segmentation

I have managed to train an unet network and at the moment trying to visulise the predictions. This issue relates to this question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73754104/u-net-image-segmentation-script-throws-an-error-215assertion-failed-dsize?noredirect=1#comment130278658_73754104). The mask should have the same size and shluld be single channel right please?

Please find the code below:

Saved Model below:

```py
#load weights to network
weights_path = unet_dir + "unet1.pt"
device = "cpu"

unet = UNet(in_channels=3, out_channels=3, init_features=8)
unet.to(device)
unet.load_state_dict(torch.load(weights_path, map_location=device))
```

Initial functions:

```py
#define augmentations 
inference_transform = A.Compose([
    A.Resize(256, 256, always_apply=True),
    A.Normalize(mean=(0.485, 0.456, 0.406), std=(0.229, 0.224, 0.225)), 
    ToTensorV2()
])

#define function for predictions
def predict(model, img, device):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        images = img.to(device)
        output = model(images)
        predicted_masks = (output.squeeze() >= 0.5).float().cpu().numpy()
        
    return(predicted_masks)

#define function to load image and output mask
def get_mask(img_path):
    image = cv2.imread(img_path)
    #assert image is not None
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    original_height, original_width = tuple(image.shape[:2])
    
    image_trans = inference_transform(image = image)
    image_trans = image_trans["image"]
    image_trans = image_trans.unsqueeze(0)
    
    image_mask = predict(unet, image_trans, device)
    #image_mask = image_mask.astype(np.int16)
    image_mask = cv2.resize(image_mask,(original_width, original_height),
                          interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    #image_mask = cv2.resize(image_mask, (original_height, original_width))
    #Y_train[n] = mask > 0.5    
    return(image_mask)
```

```py
#image example
example_path = "../input/test-image/10078.tiff"
image = cv2.imread(example_path)
#assert image is not None
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

mask = get_mask(example_path)

#masked_img = image*np.expand_dims(mask, 2).astype("uint8")

#plot the image, mask and multiplied together
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

ax1.imshow(image)
ax2.imshow(mask)
#ax3.imshow(masked_img)
```

Output:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4859/3003834023.py in <module>
     13 
     14 ax1.imshow(image)
---> 15 ax2.imshow(mask)
     16 #ax3.imshow(masked_img)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    457                 "parameter will become keyword-only %(removal)s.",
    458                 name=name, obj_type=f"parameter of {func.__name__}()")
--> 459         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    460 
    461     # Don't modify *func*'s signature, as boilerplate.py needs it.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1412     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1413         if data is None:
-> 1414             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1415 
   1416         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, interpolation_stage, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5485                               **kwargs)
   5486 
-> 5487         im.set_data(X)
   5488         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5489         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    714                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
    715             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
--> 716                             .format(self._A.shape))
    717 
    718         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid shape (2023, 2023, 256) for image data
```

Output images:

[image]

Would anyone be able to help me in this matter please?

Thanks & Best Regards

Schroter Michael

Answer (score -1):

first if you use vscode, I advice you to use this to debug :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=elazarcoh.simply-view-image-for-python-debugging

Out of my head, I would say you should sum the values over one axis, (As I image them beoing one hot encoded) :

`np.sum(A,axis = 1)`

Taken from this :

[sum numpy ndarray with 3d array along a given axis 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142135/sum-numpy-ndarray-with-3d-array-along-a-given-axis-1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).